# ¿De que manera puedo hacer que emmet me autocomplete métodos en archivos.jsx tal cual lo hace en archivos.js? OJO! métodos, no TAGS... Uso VSC

Tags: javascript, autocompletar, jsx, emmet

ya tengo hecha la config de la img y en efecto me autocompleta todo en jsx, pero no me autocompleta los métodos tal cual lo hace en js (map,filter,find, entre otros)
https://prnt.sc/1x7jh34
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué editor de código/IDE estás usando?

Comment: VSC  ...................................................